# How can I delete a remote branch in a local git repository?

Tags: git

All the remote branches are visible as remotes in my local git repository after a git fetch.

How to selectively remove the remote branches in my local repository (not in the remote repository)?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`git branch -r -d remote/branch`

You also need to reconfigure fetch to avoid fetching this branch again later

Comment: how do you reconfigure fetch?

Comment: Because [I just looked for this too](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) — you need to edit `.git/config`, and edit the section under `[remote "origin"]` or whatever. Replace `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*` with `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/github/master` to only fetch the master branch. I think you can add multiple `fetch` lines to do more branches. Not sure if you can just exclude a branch though.

Comment: It doesn't work if the remote branch was already deleted on the remote side. In this case, check the following answer from @ThomasLevesque.

Answer (score 82):

I had a slightly different but similar issue, but the solution might be useful to others who stumble on this question...

I noticed that my local repository still had remote branches that no longer existed on the remote, so I wanted to remove them. The solution is simply to fetch with the `--prune` (or `-p`) option:

```
git fetch --prune
```

Comment: This is the actual solution.

Comment: I concur with Thomas

Comment: This is the working solution, if the remote branch is already deleted on the server side. It actually syncronizes its branch references, deleting locally what doesn't already exist remotely. Up, up, up.

Comment: +1 :) Note this does not, however, remove any *local* branches one had checked out locally at one point in the past (and maybe or not pushed to remote). Those must still be removed via `git branch -d <branch>` (or possibly even `git branch -D <branch>`).

Comment: This is only the actual solution if you are trying to delete branches that are no longer in the remote.  I had to use the "git branch -r -d remote/branch" solution because I was trying to delete a branch whose remote had already been deleted.