# git/SourceTree local "branch" removal?

Tags: git

This is novice question. Using git/SourceTree after I check out someone else's branch, how do I remove that branch from my SourceTree "branch" list when I no longer want it there? I thought I simply delete the branch while not using the "also delete remote branch" option, however, SourceTree complains the branch is not fully merged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete a remote branch in a local git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940595/how-can-i-delete-a-remote-branch-in-a-local-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

In SourceTree:

1. Make sure you are not on the branch you want to delete.
2. Right click on the branch and choose `Delete [branch-name]`
3. Check the `Force delete` checkbox and click `OK`

This will delete the branch despite the warning you are getting that the branch is not fully merged.

By doing this you will lose any commits/changes on that branch that have not been merged into another branch (eg: `master`)