# Why can't i create feature branch using git flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I want to create a feature branch but when i use git flow feature start feature-name it says it already exist.

if i try to delete it it says not found

git branch -a shows this

```
 *develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/1.1
  remotes/origin/feature/1.2
  remotes/origin/feature/CM_DA_NEW_GRADUATES-82
  remotes/origin/feature/aws1.1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/week_two_task
```

is there a way to delete this entry remotes/origin/feature/CM_DA_NEW_GRADUATES-82 locally so that i can make a feature branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general in git if you want to remove the remote branch you should:

```
git push origin --delete feature/CM_DA_NEW_GRADUATES-82
```

Or slightly shorter version (note the "colon" and absence of '--delete' flag):

```
git push origin :feature/CM_DA_NEW_GRADUATES-82
```

In case you want to delete only from the local repo but want the branch to be preserved in the remote repo", you can do the following:

```
git branch -r -d remotes/origin/feature/CM_DA_NEW_GRADUATES-82
```

Read also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940595/how-can-i-delete-a-remote-branch-in-a-local-git-repository) because it shows how to configure your local repository so that you won't get it from remote next time you fetch the data.